# Open Source solution for message board on Monitor or TV?

Tags: open-source

My working company has 50+ clinics, today my boss ask about the message board (Not forum like PHPBB)

like this :
[image: http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5217/5395181976_69ba92b124_o.jpg]

It display a video, some slide message, or some image, some text in different section.
It will display on a large LCD monitor or TV.
Is it any open source solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an open source solution for something this extensive.

If you want to display text messages, twitter messages and emails on your tv screens in a message board format, along with images / video, I would use a "text to screen" software like the one we have available here http://www.firetext.com, it's not too expensive and can do everything you describe.